# Internet connection monitor with logging

Tags: networking, internet, logging, monitoring

We are having intermittent issues with our internet connection in a community house of nine people. It seems to cut out for short intervals so I am looking for an app to test connectivity at regular intervals and log it. For example to ping a host on the internet every minute or so and log the results. What I want is to log when the connection is down and for how long over a period of time. This is not an enterprise issue so I am looking for a free app or script to accomplish this.
Thanks

Comment: Which version of Linux/Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a simple ping command to accomplish this:

```
ping -i 60 domain.com > ouput.txt
```

where 60 is the time between pings. To limit the total count of pings use :

```
ping -i 60 -c 50 domain.com > ouput.txt
```

where 50 is the number (count) of pings.

There are many more options to read about on the man page of ping. To access it use:

```
man ping
```

If you want more in-depth statistics on all traffic of one machine I recommend to use an application such as `wireshark`. It is open-source and free.

[Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) can give you exact statistics on each packet of data sent and/or received by your computer. So if you only want to see if general connectivity is available I would consider this a little much. It can also be hard to figure out what to do with all this output from `wireshark`.

PS. some suggestions to ping (these are very reliable and fast but don't overdo it or they might ban your IP):

```
1.1.1.1     (cloudflare DNS)
8.8.8.8     (google DNS)
google.com
```

Comment: @ColinBondi. You are very welcome. If this answer has solved your question, you can use the ✓ to accept the solution. And mark your problem as solved.